# Two links clicked, do some action?

Tags: javascript, php, hyperlink

I want do change background color in a certain DIV when Link1 AND link2 is clicked.
Is there a simple way do do this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Not in PHP, but a million ways in JavaScript to do that

Comment: Just wondering, how are they supposed to click both DIVs _together_? With 2 mouses?

Comment: What have you tried? Please show some code. This is more to do with javascript than php.

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger I don't see OP said together....

Comment: @Shomz _when Link1 AND link2 is clicked_ Note the capital AND

Comment: actually JavaScript would be fine. I just cant find any, I guess I don't know what to "google"..

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger Assume, clicked is the state *after* clicking something... So, you click link1 - it's clicked, click link2 - it's clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Simply keep track of clicked divs and when both are finally clicked, change the background. Here is a super simple solution:

HTML

```
<div onclick="clicked(0)">1</div>
<div onclick="clicked(1)">2</div>
```

JS

```
var clickedDivs = [0,0];
function clicked(n) {
    clickedDivs[n] = 1;
    check();
}

function check() {
    if (clickedDivs[0] == clickedDivs[1] == 1)
        document.body.style.background = 'green';
}
```

Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/6Q6kK/

This example assumes you don't need to click them in order since that part wasn't mentioned in the question.

Comment: @diegoaguilar +1 Damn, completely forgot about it! :D

Comment: @diegoaguilar Are you serious now?

Comment: Lol, well, assuming the *things* he wants to modify would increase, it'll help out.

Comment: thank you very much. Now how to click them in order? forgot about that, need that too

Comment: @diegoaguilar Not really, remember that jQuery is the JS framework, not the other way round. Anything jQuery does, JS does with better performance (or the same, in 0.001% of cases). See this: http://vanilla-js.com/ There is also a ridiculous topic here about people who abuse jQuery, and use **everywhere** but I can't find it now... If someone can dig it up, please do.

Comment: @user2734766 You're welcome. Well, you can add a check to the clicked function, something like `if (n==1 && clickedDivs[0]==1) check();` (http://jsfiddle.net/6Q6kK/1/), but it might be a good idea to rewrite it a bit, now that you know how to handle it.

Comment: @diegoaguilar Found it! http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45176/when-is-use-jquery-not-a-valid-answer-to-a-javascript-question

Comment: @user2734766 Sorry, I misread that you want to click links instead of divs, but it's exactly the same principle, just put anchors instead.

Comment: @Shomz I agree with your arguments. A question of sort "Use jQuery" should definitely NOT be acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

PHP is server side language, use JavaScript to do this:

```
<a href="#" id="link1">Link 1</a>
<a href="#" id="link2">Link 2</a>
```

```
function changeBackground(link1, link2) {
   if(link1 && link2) {
      document.getElementById('Your_div_id').style.backgroundColor = 'red';
   }

}

window.onload = function() {
   var link1 = document.getElementById('link1');
   var link2 = document.getElementById('link2');
   var clicked1 = false;
   var clicked2 = false;

   link1.onclick = function() {
      clicked1 = true;
      changeBackground(clicked1, clicked2);
       return false;
   }
   link2.onclick = function() {
      clicked2 = true;
      changeBackground(clicked1, clicked2);
      return false;
   }
```

[Demo!](http://jsfiddle.net/W6yML/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<p onclick="document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.backgroundColor='FF0000';"
id="link1"><a href="#">Link 1</a></p>
<br/>
<p onclick="document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.backgroundColor='#0000FF';" 
id="link2"><a href="#">Link 2</a></p>
```